# Redis Hash/Set Storing multiple types

Tags: redis

I am new to redis so I apologize if this question seems naive. I want to create a hash of the following type:

```
item = {{"bititem":00001010000100...001010},
       {"property":1}}
```

Where bititem is a bit array created by setbit and property is a simple integer value. Is there any way to do this in redis or do I have to create different objects?

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it is not clear to me why you need the extra depth-level around `bititem`.

Also, it is not clear to me what you want to do with it afterwards. So I give you three scenario's:

**1. Serialized:**

You can always serialize your data if it involves multiple levels. Most efficient is [`MsgPack`](http://msgpack.org/), second best is JSON. You can deserialize the data in Lua-Redis when needed.

**2. Hashed:**

If you don't need multiple levels, simply do:

```
HSET item:01 bititem 00001010000100...001010
HSET item:01 property 1
```

*Only do this though*, if you **really** need to extract the different datamembers **often**. Separate members have quite some overhead. In general, I prefer to serialize the whole object (with a `SET` or a `HSET`).

**3. Bitwise enabled:**

If you want to make use of Redis' [bitwise](http://redis.io/commands/setbit) operations, you need to use simple strings (`GET/SET`). For example:

```
SET item:01:bititem "00001010000100...001010"
SET item:01:property 1
```

or even better:

```
SET item:01:bititem "00001010000100...001010"
SET item:01:properties [all-other-properties-serialized-as-msgpack]
```

Hope this helps, TW